# Tuple from dict of dict in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

i've a dict of dict in python, for getting a random value from the dict

```
words = {0:{"wake up": "aaaa"},
         1:{"look after": "bbbb"},
         2:{"turn on": "cccc"}
        }
```

i want extract the second dict (the values of a number key) from the dict words

```
(k, v) = words[random.randint(0, 22)]
```

but the error is thisone

```
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

why i need another values?

Answer (score 3):

You are accessing the dictionary with a key, which returns *just* the value:

```
value = words[random.randint(0, 22)]
```

but if your keys are all integers, you would be better off using a list instead:

```
words = [{"wake up": "aaaa"}, {"look after": "bbbb"}, {"turn on": "cccc"}]
value = random.choice(words)
```

and let `random.choice()` do all the hard work of picking one at random.

You can still use `random.choice()` with dictionary values too of course:

```
value = random.choice(list(words.values()))
```

would return a random value from the dictionary, and:

```
key, value = random.choice(list(words.items()))
```

would return a random `(key, value)` pair for you.

If you meant to extract the stored *dictionary* into a key and value, you'd have to extract just **one** key-value pair from that object; you cannot use tuple unpacking on a dictionary:

```
>>> key, value = {'foo': 'bar'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

but this works:

```
>>> key, value = next(iter({'foo': 'bar'}.items()))
>>> key, value
('foo', 'bar')
```

but perhaps you should be storing tuples instead of dictionaries if you wanted to extract a random key-value pair, or store the keys and values *directly* in the `words` dictionary.

Comment: Note that: `random.choice(list(words.values()))` is a longer and possibly less efficient way of writing `random.choice(words)`

Comment: @JonClements: No, that's not the same thing at all. That returns a random *key*.

Comment: @JonClements: Ah, the keys are all integers here; `random.choice(dictionary)` **normally** doesn't even work. `random.choice()` picks a random integer in the range `[0, len(sequence))` and returns `seq[picked_index]`, which only by coincidence works with this dictionary.

Comment: indeed - but thought you'd find it interesting - obviously not what you were expecting anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

*Summary: Method 3 is the most pythonic way to do it.*

1. Without any modification to the data structures, the following code will work for you:

   ```
   k, v = words[random.randint(0, 2)].items()[0]
   ```

   However, this is not the best (& pythonic) way to do it.
2. If your inner dict always has a single key-value pair, then there is really no need to keep it as a dict. Rather, keep the inner data as a tuple.

   ```
   words = {0: ("wake up", "aaaa"),
       1:("look after", "bbbb"),
       2:("turn on", "cccc")
   }

   # Now, the following line should work fine
   k, v = words[random.randint(0, 2)]
   ```
3. And If there is no restriction on the outer data structure either, then use list or tuple as  follows:

   ```
   words = (
       ("wake up", "aaaa"),
       ("look after", "bbbb"),
       ("turn on", "cccc")
   )

   # Now, the random.choice can be used
   k, v = random.choice(words)
   ```